Microsoft Graph Authentication from backend
I am creating a portal to create meeting for microsoft teams and using graph api but to get the refresh token we'll have to login for which I'd need to share the microsoft account credentials to other members which i dont want.
So is there any way i can use the credentials from database to get the refresh token and use that to access graph api.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
